# Replace text error in Jquery

Tags: jquery

After AJAX operation, I need to change Icon + Text + Color from TO DO to DONE.

If I just do like that, it works ( But text is not changed)!

```
panel.find('.status-icon').removeClass().addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok  status-icon');
panel.find('.text-orange-600').removeClass().addClass('text-success'); //.text(configured);
```

When I try to change text,

```
panel.find('.text-orange-600').removeClass().addClass('text-success').text(configured)
```

Text changes, but icon disapear

Here is my HTML

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-styled" href="#accordion-styled-group{!! $key !!}">
<div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="text-orange-600">{{ trans('crud.configure') }}
            <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-exclamation-sign  status-icon"></i></span>

</div>
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: What does the markup look like? The `.text()` function will overwrite the complete contents of the element with the string you provide, so is there perhaps some other HTML that needs to stick aroudn?

Comment: added HTML as you asked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML you're replacing includes the `<i>` element which is where the icon is applied. (Side note: that's weird, and if you have any control over the HTML don't use an `<i>` to attach an icon.)

If you *do* have control over the HTML, make sure the text (and ***only*** the text) is in a `<span>` with a class you can target specifically.

```
<span class="only-the-text-here-and-absolutely-no-other-markup">Hello</span>
```

If you don't have control over the HTML, this gets a lot thornier. You can try to parse what's inside the `.text-orange-600` and put the icon back in. If you can predict what text is already there (e.g., if it's always either `Hello` or `Goodbye`) you can try to do a straight replacement (`foo.html( foo.html().replace(old_text, new_text)`)

Those options aren't very good, though. At that point you're taking a chance that the markup isn't going to change or be in another language or have a funny amount of space in it or whatever else.

By far the best solution is to have whoever does control the HTML write it so that the things you'd want to control are all in their own individual elements (and the `<i>` element doesn't appear anywhere).

```
<div class="panel-heading">
    <span class="text-orange-600">{{ trans('crud.configure') }}
        <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-exclamation-sign  status-icon"></i>
        <span class="text-goes-here">TEXT!</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have full control on my HTML. I can extract <i> from <span> but then I don't how to get them in the same line :(

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: In my case, TEXT is {{ trans('crud.configure') }} ( it is just laravel generated variable, so I'm a little confused in your example

Comment: I tried it like that, but still have icon and text in 2 lines :                                                         <span class="text-success">
                                                             <i class="glyphicon text-success glyphicon-ok  status-icon"></i>
                                                            <span class="text-goes-here">{{ trans('crud.configured') }}</span>
                                                        </span>

Comment: It seems to be working now, it was in 2 lines because of small css issue. Tx for your help!